# Cannot pass an object to a public method as a class

Tags: java

Here is my code from the main file (Airport.java) in java

```
AirportMarker airSource = airports.get(source);
AirportMarker airDest = airports.get(dest);

SimpleLinesMarker sl = new SimpleLinesMarker(route.getLocations(), route.getProperties());
                
airSource.addRoute(sl);
airDest.addRoute(sl);
```

and here is the class AirportMarker

```
public static List<SimpleLinesMarker> routes;

public void addRoute(SimpleLinesMarker route) {

    routes.add(route);
};
```

and here is the error

```
Unfolding Map v0.9.7 (UCSD edition)
No OpenGL renderer. Using Java2DMapDisplay.
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at module6.AirportMarker.addRoute(AirportMarker.java:102)
    at module6.AirportMap.setup(AirportMap.java:130)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2365)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:245)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2260)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What is the error I am getting?

Comment: Generally the error is provided in the post rather than letting other guess the error. Although, a quick check, are you sure you have initialised the list?

Comment: Posted the error message

Comment: As @Quarter asked, have you initialized ``routes``?